# on:tap adding a iframe in AMP

Tags: html, iframe, amp-html

I have created an AMP page and there i have to add an iframe having PDF To display,

Two Question in it:-

1. How to add iFrame in amp with on:tap event (If a user click on a button the iframe should be add)
2. Is it Allowed to add non-AMP page as iframe in an amp page.

Comment: I have got answer of second question non-AMP iframe is allowed but that shuld use https and  it will be loaded async.

Comment: 1. On your first question: add your code, I'll try to help you.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov There is no code just AMP page and i want an event based action in that if a visitor come and click on  "ReadPDF" Button An iframe Tag get added in page. i don't want changing the src in iframe and make it visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How to add iFrame in amp with on:tap event (If a user click on a button the iframe should be add)

Try something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ⚡>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>My AMP Page</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="self.html" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1" />
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
  <style amp-boilerplate>
    body {
      -webkit-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      -moz-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      -ms-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }

      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }

      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }

    @-ms-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }

      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }

    @-o-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }

      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }

    @keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }

      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <noscript>
    <style amp-boilerplate>
      body {
        -webkit-animation: none;
        -moz-animation: none;
        -ms-animation: none;
        animation: none;
      }
    </style>
  </noscript>
  <style amp-custom>
    .wrapper {
      max-width: 700px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="wrapper">
    <h1>My AMP Tap iframe</h1>
    <button type="button" on="tap:AMP.setState({ myIframeUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pdf995.com%2Fsamples%2Fpdf.pdf&embedded=true' })" [hidden]="myIframeUrl">Load my PDF iframe</button>
    <amp-iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="https://google.com/" width="1" height="1" layout="responsive" [src]="myIframeUrl" [hidden]="!myIframeUrl" hidden>
      <div placeholder>PDF coming</div>
    </amp-iframe>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

**Live demo:** https://codepen.io/alexandr-kazakov/pen/wvzjqbj

---

> 2. Is it Allowed to add non-AMP page as iframe in an amp page.

Of course, for example, we can insert a google map or YouTube player into an amp-iframe, although they are not related to AMP.

Comment: I was thinking to add whole iframe insted of changing src url, so one request can be reduced  isn't there a way to add the same, Anyway Thanks, this would help me.

Comment: Does this work for the amp-youtube component to load the thumbnail image and after click on it, loads the video?